# Symfony 4: pass custom data to Form Collection prototype

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

CollectionType field has special 'prototype' variable when 'allow_add' option is set to true. This variable can be used to render prototype html like this:

```
data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.collectionfieldname.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
```

It looks like 'prototype' is simply an instance of collection children FormView built with partial data (e.g. name is set to "__name__" while most other vars are left blank).

Where all this magic happens? Is it possible to modify what data is passed to prototype view while building form? For example, I would like to change default value of "value" variable from blank to "__val__" (outside of Twig template).

Comment: Did you try buildView?

Comment: Looks like I figured it out (see my own answer below). View is created in buildView method of CollectionType class, but prototype form is built in buildForm method of the same class.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to own question - values defined in "entry_options" setting are used to build prototype. It is possible to pass these values to form builder like this:

```
$builder
            ->add('email', CollectionType::class, array(
                ...
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'someoption' => 'somevalue',
                ),
                ...
                ))
```

If this is not enough, default behaviour can be modified by overriding "buildForm" method in "CollectionType" class which is responsible for collecting options and building prototype:

```
class CollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['allow_add'] && $options['prototype']) {
            $prototypeOptions = array_replace(array(
                'required' => $options['required'],
                'label' => $options['prototype_name'].'label__',
            ), $options['entry_options']);

            if (null !== $options['prototype_data']) {
                $prototypeOptions['data'] = $options['prototype_data'];
            }

            $prototype = $builder->create($options['prototype_name'], $options['entry_type'], $prototypeOptions);
            $builder->setAttribute('prototype', $prototype->getForm());
        }

        ...
    }
...
}
```